# Set height of element to screen height - Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to set the height of a `div` element to the height of the screen minus a fixed number of pixels.

I'm building a single page application with angular and right now it is in it's infancy. The page currently consists of a single header bar which is a fixed 24px height.

Directly below this header is the `<app-root></app-root>` component which is auto-generated by angular, which contains a single div, `<div id="work-area"><div>`.

What I want to do is have this `#work-area` div extend from the bottom of the header to the bottom of the screen, something like `screen.height - 24px` if this was to be done in pure javascript.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I tried a few things so far:

- Embed a script into the angular HTML template which contains javascript code to set the width. This did not work because angular does not support embedded script tags.
- I tried setting the height using pure CSS, I couldn't get this to work and I'm pretty sure pure CSS won't accomplish this goal, but if it does, it would be the preferred method.
- Finally I had a look at the `ngStyle` attribute directive, but this only takes pure CSS rather than javascript so I ran into the same problem as above.

Below are my files incase it makes the problem clearer:

```
//app-root component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<div id="work-area"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WorkspacePrototype</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="overflowing-bar">
      <div id="header">

      </div>
   </div>


   <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
 </body>
 </html>
```

global styles.css

```
body, html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.overflowing-bar {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header/*, #footer*/ {
    width: inherit;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with entirely with css, using the `calc` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

```
#work-area {
    height: calc(100vh - 24px);
}
```